# Angular jasmine unit test error with 'and' on a spy

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Can anyone shed some light on this error I'm seeing in my Jasmine unit tests where I'm creating a spy on a mock service call and trying to return a value?

This is an example of the spy:

```
mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['getSomeId']);
mockService.getSomeId.and.returnValue(10);
```

When i run ng test, the following error shows up in the console window - but the test actually passes successfully in the browser:

**error TS2339: Property 'and' does not exist on type '() => string'.
src/app/services/myservice.service.spec.ts(57,45): error TS2339: Property 'and' does not exist on type '(controller: string) => string'.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `(controller: string) => string` the signature of the actual implementation? Do you see the same error when using `(mockService.getSomeId as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(10);`?

Comment: You're right, casting it that way worked fine - with that, I realized i was setting the type of my mock (spy) service incorrectly.

Answer (score 8):

Alex shed some light on the issue - I was strongly typing the mock service as the service type, instead of a spy type.  Once I removed the type, the error went away.